# Can i create Mifare 1K Classic card to Apple Wallet Pass?

Tags: ios, applepay, apple-wallet

**Hi All,**

I'm exploring the possibility of replacing physical access control cards which uses Mifare 1k Classic with digital cards using Apple Wallet Passes & Google Pay.

It was successful with Google Pay, but it turned out to be more difficult with Apple.

I have tried using [Passkit](https://passkit.com/) but the NFC card was not recognized by the card reader at the door.

Have anyone tried this before? is it possible?

Comment: It is not possible.  Apps do not have access to host card emulation on iOS.  Through the Apple Access partner program it is possible to add access cards to the Apple Wallet but these still require specific support in the reader.  They won't work as generic Mifare cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a reader that is either VAS/SmartTap compatible (https://www.passninja.com/tutorials/nfc-protocols/what-is-vas) OR ECP 2.0 compatible (https://github.com/kormax/apple-enhanced-contactless-polling)

Or if you're willing to swap or augment your reader to something that is VAS/SmartTap compatible, like this: https://flomio.com/shop/vas/flovas-mini-nfc-pass-scanner-module/

Than you can use services like [passninja.com](https://www.passninja.com/), or [passkit.com](https://passkit.com/) or even your own passes (with Apple and Googles permissions/entitlements) to issue passes.